# Dealing with attachment file in jquery.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, download

In my web page I have a button for downloading a file. If there's no file to download, then I'd like to show a message while staying on the same page. The following javascript code works when there's a file to download (id is file id):

```
function downloadFile(id) {
    window.location = '/myapp.com/download_file/' + id;
}
```

My server writes the file content into the response body and sets 'Content-Disposition' header to 'attachment'.

Now, when there's no file I'd like to return some text saying that there was no file to download. So I'd like to do something like below:

```
function downloadFile(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myapp.com/download_file/' + id,
        success: function () {
            //if (attachemnt) {
            //    download file: just pass response to the browser?
            //} else {
            //    show error text
            //}
        },
        error: function () {
          //show error message
        }
    });
}
```

So, my question is:

1. How can I implement the above functionality?
2. Specifically, if there's an attachment file in the response, is it possible just to pass the response to the browser, so that the browser can handle file download?

**UPDATE**:
I can handle 'no file' case now:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{{ path('download_prev_other_data', {'other_data_id':form.vars.value.getOtherDataId() }) }}',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var header = jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
        if (header && header.indexOf('attachment') === 0) {
            //pass the original response to the browser
        } else {
            alert(data); //data is just text in my case explaining there was no file
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

So, my 2nd question, "how to pass the original response to the browser" is not answered yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is are ready plugin for this with source code: [jquery.fileDownload.js Library](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)

Comment: Yes, I know this. I just thought maybe I can go without an additional library.

Comment: @synergetic Then you have to mention it in your post that Idon't want to use any plugin's.

Comment: @synergetic it is really difficult to write such funcionality from scratch because you need to handle desktop and mobile browsers (and for example some bugs in iOS). You could look here: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js to see full source code of above plugin. It is using hiding iframe and comunicates with it

Answer (score 0):

You **can not** use ajax for file download when rely on standard browser possibilities. I think that best solution is to use hidden iframe.
Create `iframe` on page startup with empty content and empty `src`. then when you want to download file just update iframe's `src` with file url. Before you need to prepare `load` event handler for `iframe`.  Handler should check iframe content (e.g. body) for error message. If so - you can display custom message.
You can not handle success (afaik) becouse browser automatically handles it and displays 'save as' dialog.

*Note:*

- To get iframe body use: `$('#frame').contents().find('body')`.
- It's browser dependent when `load` event is trigger for `iframe` - be ready to handle it also after main page is loaded (empty/initial `iframe` state)

I think, that you can also consider to use different request for check & for download attachment. Check it with `POST` request and check on server side whether attachment can be found. If so response OK status, and then use `GET` request on client side for retrieve attachment. In this case usually `window.open` is enough to download file. Browser sends `GET` request itself and handles download.

*Note:*
Remember to send header with attachment content response, like below:
`"Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=yourFileName"`